# An obvious probability conjecture I cannot prove

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Introduce the partial ordering $\leq$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\forall (x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2, \ (x_1,y_1) \leq (x_2,y_2) \iff x_1 \leq x_2$ and $\ y_1 \leq y_2$. Using this, suppose $X,Y,X',Y'$ are independent random variables with range $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\forall z \in \mathbb{R}^2$
\begin{align*} 
P(X \geq z) &\leq P(X' \geq z) \ \ \ \text{and}  \\ 
P(Y \geq z) &\leq P(Y' \geq z).
\end{align*}
Informally, the distribution of $X'$ is more northeast than that of $X$, and the distribution of $Y'$ is more northeast than that of $Y$. Adding the random variables like vectors (recall they are independent), it seems obvious because $X'$ is more northeast than $X$, and $Y'$ is more northeast than $Y$, that $X'+Y'$ should be more northeast than $X+Y$. That is, it should be true
$$
\forall z \in \mathbb{R}^2, \ P(X+Y \geq z) \leq P(X'+Y' \geq z).
$$
However I have been trying to prove this for a long time and have not been successful.

It is easy to generalize this thought process/problem to more r.v.'s or different spaces with different partial orderings. I proved a simpler version of this problem for $1$ dimension. The proof was long, however the methods there have not generalized to $2$ dimensions.

Comment: Try $$P(X + Y \geq z) = \int P(X + y \geq z)dF_Y(y)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X, Y$ are independent and $X', Y$ are independent,
$$P(X + Y \geq z) = \int P(X + y \geq z)dF_Y(y) \leq \int P(X' + y \geq z)dF_Y(y) = P(X' + Y \geq z).$$
Then since $Y, X'$ are independent and $Y', X'$ are independent, the same argument yields
$$P(X' + Y \geq z) \leq P(X' + Y' \geq z).$$
So it turns out we only need pairwise independence to get this inequality.